# Why "UUID.randomUUID()" doesn't work in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I installed APP Engine platform on my eclip to build app engine app.

The app use this cose `user.setUniversalRoomID(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));` & it runs just fine in eclipse.

But after deployed to App Engine, `UUID.randomUUID()` comes out like a `null`

**Why `UUID.randomUUID()` doesn't work in Google App Engine?**

Comment: That seems unlikely. Can you debug it a bit more?

Comment: replace String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()) with UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: i have worked with UUIDs on app engine so it is possible. I would not use `String.valueOf` as Xoce suggested. Additionally this sounds like it could be one of the things that happen when you debug with Java 8 locally and deploy a Java 7 compliant version to app engine.